# Nomad failing to pull from GCP container registery due to docker auth

Tags: google-container-registry, nomad

This is my server config:

```
client {
    enabled = true
    servers = ["127.0.0.1:4647"]

}
```

I get an error of `us.gcr.io/PROJECTID/IMAGE/NAME:latest: API error (404): {"message":"pull access denied for us.gcr.io/PROJECTID/IMAGE/NAME, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'"}`

I'm trying to pull an image from google cloud container registery.

How do I instruct nomad to use the docker authentication via gcloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

And the server config:

```
client {
    enabled = true
    servers = ["127.0.0.1:4647"]

  options   = {
    "docker.auth.helper"     = "gcloud"
  }
}
```

I have no idea how this works when I'll need other docker auth helpers... But oh well